# How to exclude links/images so that they are not affected by fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Right now, the fancybox plugin is being used in all my images links.
I can't really control this right now.

But I need to exclude one page. How to do that?
(Maybe excluding a div with a certain class or ID).

Comment: use of jquery selector will help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding lightboxing I always use prettyPhoto, because:

1. it's very much flexible and it has an API which enables you to make your images totally and fully customizable without binding any data to your inline images
2. Also if you are developing using a server side language then using this API makes your code more readable and maintainable.

Here is the pretty photo website: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

and here is the API documentation (Bottom of the page): http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/

Comment: Actually the key is you don't need to bing anything to your image!, all you do is to call a javascript function when your image/link is clicked.